# Distinguir entre mail y contraseña por : en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que a la hora de que Python lea un archivo *.txt* distinga entre el mail y la contraseña por la separación de un :. Os pongo un ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando:

```
Python abre el documento y lee solo la primera línea
```

Y después viene lo que digo de la separación por :

```
Python lee el texto hasta : ( este sería el mail ), lo inserta en la página web, Python lee el texto a partir del : ( esta sería la contraseña ), lo inserta en la página web
```

El tema de insertar lo en la página ( selenium ) lo se, lo único que no se es si se puede hacer lo de leer hasta el :

Comment: El archivo sería `email:contraseña` o `contraseña:email` ¿siempre tendría el mismo orden o dependería del fichero? ¿tienes una pareja por línea? Si o he entendido bien básicamente sería un csv lo que tienes

Comment: Siento no haber especificado, sería ```email:contraseña```, siempre seguiría el mismo orden y no, hay solo un ```email:contraseña``` por línea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esencia tienes un csv, usando `:` como separador. Puedees usar el módulo csv de la stdlib sin más. Debemos tener en cuenta dos cosas:

- El email puede tener : como carácter, pero para que sea válido debería ir acotado, por lo que no debe ser un problema.
- Supongo que la contraseña podría contener `:`, esto si sería un problema si no se creo el documento como un csv válido. No obstante, como solo tenemos dos campos y todo lo que sigue al email es la contraseña podemos reolverlo de forma simple.

---

```
import csv


with open("accounts.txt") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=":")
    for email, *contraseña in reader:
        contraseña = "".join(contraseña)
        print(f"Email: {email}, Contraseña: {contraseña}")
```

Para el archivo:

```
foo@foomail.com:adaafcaaf
bar@foomail.com:afafda:faf:afds
"stack:overflow"@foomail.com:abcdef
```

La salida sería:

> ```
> Email: foo@foomail.com, contraseña: adaafcaaf
> Email: bar@foomail.com, contraseña: afafda:faf:afds
> Email: stack:overflow@foomail.com, contraseña: abcdef
> ```

Comment: esto solo lo debería repetir tantas  veces como ```email:contraseña``` tenga?

Comment: El código retorna todas las parejas, no tienes que repetirlo por cada linea del fichero como puedes ver en el ejemplo. Si quieres obtener un email por cada vez, puedes agregarlos a una lista y luego indizar o iterar sobre ella dónde los necesites o puedes eliminar el `for` y usar `email, *contraseña = next(reader)` manejando la excepción `StopIteration` cuando no queden más...